# Live threads VisualVM

Tags: java, spring-boot, visualvm

Здравсвуйте!
Есть небольшое приложение на spring-boot, один из методов, который обрабатывает входящий запрос создает

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int N)
```

при каждом запросе может N может варьироваться примерно от 3 до 10 нитей. 
После выполнения метода все завершаю (как я думаю, если не прав поставьте на путь истинный)

```
executor.shutdownNow();
executor.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Начал осваивать VisualVM и столкнулся с тем что либо не понимаю трактование live threads либо не понимаю как закрывать ExecutorService. Запускаю приложение live threads показывает значение 20 +- нитей, обращаюсь к данному методу раз 40 например, и количество live threads становится примерно 60-65. Есть еще такое значение как Daemon на вкладке Threads - он стабильный с момента запуска 30.

От сюда у меня возникает вопрос, что же такое live threads и правильно ли я завершаю ExecutorService? А так же если стоит задача в методе создавать многопоточные вычисления, то необходимо ведь пул потоков переиспользовать, но не могу додуматься как это делать верно, буду очень благодарен за какой нибудь набросок/пример.

Comment: Если у вас spring boot, то там наверняка потоки создаются еще и на обработку каждого запроса. Используйте ThreadFactory (проще всего взять из гуавы), чтобы устанавливать потокам имена и, таким образом, ориентироваться в них.